# Is it safe to search through serialized array as a string? (MySql query)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

I have a serialized array like this

```
a:6:{i:0;i:6;i:1;i:65;i:2;i:56;i:3;i:87;i:4;i:48;i:5;i:528;}
```

For example i want to make a mysql query like this

```
$id_serialize = 6;
"SELECT id FROM table WHERE col LIKE '% i:" . $id_serialize . "; %'"
```

Is it possible to get a conflict (for example the numbers are repeated etc.) as a consequence of this query ?

Is there another more effective and correct way to find number in array without unserializing the array and without looping ?

Comment: i wouldn't use like on a serialized string. it's not reliable.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on data you are going to store. For integers it is highly possible.

> `a:6:{i:0;i:6;i:1;i:65;i:2;i:56;i:3;i:87;i:4;i:48;i:5;i:528;}`

This actually menas:

```
a:6:{...} - array of 6 elements
i:0;i:6; - first element, id 0, value 6
i:1;i:65; - second element, id 1, value 65
and so on
```

If you will get to array of 7 elements, 7th element definition would be: `i:6;i:34` And this would collide with `i:0;i:6;`. Your query would return results with id 6 along with results with value 6.

A bit more about arrays anatomy http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.serialize.php#66147

Answer (score 1):

```
a:1:{i:0;s:5:"i:42;";}
```

Oops.

It's extremely hard to search within data formats which allow arbitrary content. It's the same reason why regexen are [simply unsuited for (X|HT)ML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/476). You should *really* be normalising the data and store each value in its own column/row.

Comment: which is the best way to get the desired result ?

Comment: I don't know what the desired result is. Can you normalise your table structure to store those values individually?

Comment: Not in this case as the table will be really too huge and it will be more difficult to select.

Comment: I doubt it will be larger in storage size than a serialised string or harder to select than *impossible*. Maybe you have the wrong idea of what I'm suggesting. I'm saying you should make a new table, with two columns `table_id` (the primary id of your current `table`) and `value` (the values you're currently serialising). Then each value is inserted as a separate row, and you select it with a `JOIN` query. Simple, proper use of an RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain of the contents of the array - that is, if you know that all the items in the array are numbers - you should be able to use your method without too much trouble. If anything else makes it into the array you may start getting false results.